# getting data from server in cycle

Tags: c, client, cycle

my task is get from server data of an file with HTTP protocol 
but problem is that i dont know the size of the content so i iterate through read func to get data from socked but it iterates every time only once i dont know really why

```
int res, len, total, boolk = 0, p=0;
 while ((res = read(client_socket,bufferOut,4095)) > 0)
{
    bufferOut[res]= '\0';
    if(p==0)
    {
        buffer = calloc(strlen(bufferOut)+1,sizeof(char));
        }
        else
        {
            buffer = realloc(buffer,strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char)+strlen(bufferOut)+1*sizeof(char));
        }
        strcat(buffer,bufferOut);
        if(isEnough(bufferOut)!=0 && boolk == 0)
        {
            index = getIndex(buffer);
            kk = getCode(buffer);
            len = getLen(buffer);
            boolk = 1;
        }
        if(strlen(bufferOut)>=len+index && boolk == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        p++;
    }
```

function isEnough only looks if full http header arrived getIndex get lenght of header and  getLen get length of that file so i wanted to iterate until buffer is same lenght as header  file which should be

Answer (score 0):

You're working much too hard.

```
int
read_until_enough(int client_socket, char **buf_out, size_t *buflen_out)
{
    char *rdbuf = xmalloc(INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE);
    size_t buflen = 0, bufalloc = INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE;

    for (;;) {
        ssize_t n = recv(client_socket, rdbuf + buflen, bufalloc - buflen);
        if (n <= 0) goto recv_failure;
        if (is_enough(rdbuf, buflen)) break;

        buflen += n;
        if (buflen == bufalloc) {
            bufalloc *= 2;
            rdbuf = xrealloc(rdbuf, bufalloc);
        }
    }
    *rdbuf_out = rdbuf;
    *buflen_out = buflen;
    return 0;

recv_failure:;
    int save_errno = errno;
    free(rdbuf);
    errno = save_errno;
    *rdbuf_out = 0;
    *buflen_out = 0;
    return -1;
}
```

Please note that `is_enough` now takes the size of the received data as an argument, caller gets both the received data and its size, and the buffer is NOT nul-terminated.  HTTP is a binary-transparent protocol; you MUST NOT<sup>[rfc2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119)</sup> assume that you never receive nul bytes.

Please also note that `is_enough` is stateless and is expected to do *all* of the parsing.  This is better separation of concerns.  Worry about the performance cost of re-parsing the HTTP headers each time around the loop only after you have everything working.

Finally, the functions [`xmalloc` and `xrealloc`](https://www.eyrie.org/%7Eeagle/software/rra-c-util/xmalloc.html) are wrappers around `malloc` and `realloc` that either succeed or crash the program.  I am using them here to avoid cluttering up the example with error-recovery logic for memory allocation.  You will have to decide whether they are appropriate for whatever you're doing.